# Method to return an array from java to shell script

Tags: java, shell

I have written a shell script(.sh) which calls a java program. After some computation the java code has an array. I want to return this array back to the shell script. Is there any method by which it is possible? Thank you for all the help

Comment: It really depends on kind of information stored in the array.

Comment: If these are integers, you might want to save them into file and then read from the script

Comment: @Anonymous - `System.out.println`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the java use `System.out.println("a b c");` with the variables of your array.

Call it from .sh something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(java -jar myexecutable.jar)
array=($output)
for i in "${array[@]}"
do :
   echo $i
done
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped